How to validate logicapp output? which arrived 2 rows through for each loop Inner - 'Rows' and outer items('rows')
I have created an logic app, and got output json result {
"name": "endData",
"value": "[ {"startdate" : "01/01/2014","enddate" : "31/01/2014","startdate" : "01/02/2014","enddate" : "28/02/2014"} ]"
} and need to validate my output json since not correct it seems
I tried jsonlint for validation, but the expected output couldn't be make like this {
"startdate" : "01/01/2014",
"enddate" :  "31/01/2014"
},
{
"startdate" : "01/02/2014",
"enddate" :  "28/02/2014"
}
] this is required

You are trying to validate whether the json is valid or nor? Or you want to convert the json to correct format?

please share your workflow diagram


https://i.sstatic.net/ZHCoH0mS.jpg 2. https://i.sstatic.net/V8sR5oth.jpg pl refer these 2 of my workflows. I need to convert to correct format through my workflow (loops)


You can format the JSON data using below workflow-

Please note if you want to format it using Parse Json action then consider having unique parameters in the payload.
code-
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@substring(variables('Data'), indexOf(variables('Data'), '['), sub(length(variables('Data')), indexOf(variables('Data'), '[')))",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Compose_2": {
                "inputs": "@concat(replace(substring(outputs('Compose'), 0, sub(length(outputs('Compose')), 3)), ',\"startdate', '},{ \"startdate'))",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Data",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "{ \"name\": \"endData\", \"value\": \"[ {\"startdate\" : \"01/01/2014\",\"enddate\" : \"31/01/2014\",\"startdate\" : \"01/02/2014\",\"enddate\" : \"28/02/2014\"} ]\" }"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {},
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}

Output-


Dear Afrin, Excellent thank u excellent reply.
